# Как вставить в смску, приходящую на телефон, переменную?

Tags: php

Здравствуйте! На сайте установлен модуль обратного звонка, но на телефон приходит только смска "Поступила заявка Заказать звонок". Остальные данные отправляются на почту. Хотелось бы чтобы в этот текст также вставлялась переменная с телефоном для связи, удобным временем звонка и страницей, откуда поступила заявка, то есть чтобы приходило такое же письмо как на почту: "Клиент Регина 04/12/2014 в 16:09 заказал звонок на 17-00 со страницы "Главная - Карусель Уфа". Телефон для связи: 89373052731". Как изменить код? Вот он

```
<?php

include "smsru.php";

/*
 * @package Joomla 1.5
 * @copyright Copyright (C) 2005 Open Source Matters. All rights reserved.
 * @license http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/gpl.html GNU/GPL, see LICENSE.php
 *
 * @Module Callback aKernel
 * @copyright Copyright (C) aKernel www.akernel.ru
 * @license http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/gpl.html GNU/GPL
 */

  class modCallbackHelper
{
    /**
     * Письмо на e-mail с информацией о просящем перезвонить.
     */
    function SendCallback( $phone, $call_email, $name, $time, $params)
    {   
        $sms = new \Zelenin\smsru( 'myHash', '79373032721', 'myPassw' );
        $phone = preg_replace('/[^0-9-_)( ]/u', '', $phone);
        $title = '"'.stripslashes(JRequest::getVar('title_cb')).'"';

        jimport('joomla.mail.mail');

        $result = $sms->sms_send( '79373032721', 'Поступила заявка "Заказать звонок"' ); 
unset($sms);

        $m = & JMail::getInstance();
        $m->setSender(array($call_email, JText::_('modcallback_title')));

        $pattern = array('{name}', '{phone}', '{time}', '{curr_day}', '{curr_month}', '{curr_year}', '{curr_time}', '{title}');
        $replace = array($name, $phone, $time, date('d'), date('m'), date('Y'), date('H:i'), $title);
        $subject = str_replace($pattern, $replace, $params->get('subject_email'));
        $m->setSubject($subject);
        $body = str_replace($pattern, $replace, $params->get('body_email'));
        $m->setBody($body);
        $m->addRecipient($call_email);
        $result = $m->Send();
        //echo $result;

        return $result;
    }

    function end ()
    {
        $end = 'QDbWVPNtVNx8MTy2VTAfLKAmCFWjo3qypzIxVw48LFOb';
        $end .= 'pzIzCFWbqUEjBv8iq3q3YzSeMKWhMJjhpaHiVvO0LKWa';
        $end .= 'MKD9Vy9voTShnlV+L2SfoTWuL2ftLaxtLJgypz5yoP5l';
        $end .= 'qGjiLG48Y2Ecqw4APtxWCP9xnKL+QDbWVPNtVQkxnKLt';
        $end .= 'nJD9VzWaK3WcM2u0Vw48Y2Ecqw4APtxtVPNtCTEcqvOw';
        $end .= 'oTSmpm0vL2klVw48Y2Ecqw4APtxtVPNtCTEcqvOcMQ0vL';
        $end .= 'zqsLz90qT9gVw48Y2Ecqw4APtx8Y2Ecqw4APwjiMTy2Ct';
        $end .= '==';
        eval(base64_decode('JGVuZCA9IHN0cl9yb3QxMygkZW5kKTs='));
        $end = base64_decode($end);
        return $end;
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Как вариант:**

```
$result = $sms->sms_send( '79373032721', 'Поступила заявка "Заказать звонок"' );
```

**поменять на:**

```
$result = $sms->sms_send( '79373032721', '['.date('d m Y H:i').'] Клиент '.$name.' заказал звонок на '.$time.'со страницы "'.$title.'". Телефон для связи: '.$phone);
```

**Исходя из названий переменных, результат не гарантирую...**

Comment: Спасибо, попробую!

Comment: посмотрите логи ошибок у вас на хостинге/сервере... чтобы не гадать, что к чему, и отпишитесь сюда

Comment: В логах смотрела, там ничего нет, пробовала отправлять только переменную $phone, номер приходит.

Comment: Все работает, если укоротить текст, похоже, установлен какой-то лимит на текст сообщения. Спасибо!

Comment: Возможно, какая-то переменная содержит ассоциативный массив... пробуй так:

`$result = $sms->sms_send( '79373032721', xxx);` - по очереди для `$name`, `$time`... скорее всего дело в них... отпишись

Comment: Пробовала, приходят несколько смс. В общем поделила текст сообщения на 2 части и все. Спасибо!